# How I can count second dimension in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
    $array[][second][][]
```

I need to count the numbers of element that they are located in the second box.

Comment: Please post the array

Comment: `count($array[][second])` http://php.net/manual/de/function.count.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should count this with foreach statement

```
$count=0;
foreach($array as $counting)
{
count+=$counting['first']['second'];
}
```